# postgres \copy command gives the error : ERROR: syntax error at or near "to"

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to copy the contents of a table to a csv file. I used this command :

\copy (select * from table) to '/tmp/a.csv' with delimiter ',';

this gave an error :  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to"

I tried to use copy instead of \copy, which gave the message :
ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.

1) I don't have superuser access to the unix machine or postgres.
2) I didn't understand the HINT here. Is there any other way for me to output the content of the table to a .csv file ?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Try \copy (select * from table) to '/tmp/a.csv' CSV DELIMITER  ',';